# How to open closed stdin subprocess again?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, error-handling, subprocess

I have a code which will run CMD inside the Python
It will ask for input send it to CMD and wait for output (in the same process)
I tried the code below:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdin_copy = os.fdopen(os.dup(sys.stdin.fileno()), sys.stdin.mode)
while True:
    cmd = input("$")
    p.stdin.write(bytes(str(cmd + "\n").encode("utf-8"))
    p.stdin.close()
    print(p.stdout.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

Output:

```
$cd H:\\
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.195]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

H:\PythonProjects\DatabaseTest>cd H:\\

H:\>
$cd H:\\MyPython\\
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:/PythonProjects/DatabaseTest/c.py", line 6, in <module>
    p.stdin.write(bytes(str(cmd + "\n").encode("utf-8")))
ValueError: write to closed file

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It runs the first command, but gives the error second time ( after closing the stdin )

I searched everywhere but can't find anything related to this

Comment: You're closing your end of the pipe, and CMD will see this broken pipe as a signal to exit. The solution is to not do that. The problem is more complicated than you think. You need two threads to read by line in a loop, one for  `p.stdout` and one for `p.stderr`. The output lines should be queued and timestamped so they can be interleaved properly as responses to input commands written to `p.stdin`. Also, you can't assume UTF-8. CMD uses the console input/output codepages if it's attached to a console, which it will be with how you're running it. The console defaults to the OEM codepage.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to use two threads for this work

Comment: Create a function that takes a file and a queue. It loops over `f.readline()` until it reads an empty string. Each line gets `put` in the queue as the tuple `(time.time(), line)`. The main thread sends a command to `p.stdin` and polls the stdout and stderr queues until it gets a known response in stdout. I suggest you start the shell with a unique prompt that you can identify, e.g. `prompt = 'SPAM_SHELL<{}>'.format(uuid.uuid4());` `cmd = 'cmd.exe /k prompt {}'.format(prompt.replace('<', '$L').replace('>', '$G'))`.

Comment: Create the process with `bufsize=0` to avoid having to flush `p.stdin`. Be aware that external commands you run via this shell should not be interactive unless they have an option to disable buffering their output when the standard streams aren't console files.